# BGE: How to create a countdown timer without using debug or python?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, text-object

Is it possible to create a timer in the Blender game engine without using DeBug or python? I can create point systems using dynamic text, but just can't figure out how to create a timer.

Comment: In the title you mention logic bricks, is this for the game engine?

Answer (score 4):

You can add a game property to an object, of type "Timer". For my BGE project, I created an Empty named "Clock", just for this purpose. It has one game property "GAME_TIME", as shown on this screenshot:

[image: Timer]

You can use this property to keep track of time, as it'll increase as long as the game is running. You can also set it to 0.0 to restart the timer.